# Logistic regression coefficients

Tags: logistic-regression, coefficients

I am doing logistic regression with 3 attributes. According to my data set I am expecting all coefficients to be positive. But it gives me both positive and negative coefficients. Is it possible to have all positive coefficients using logistic regression.